# Python: can not save all links to a dict in json file, only the last one

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I wrote this code in python to get all the links and to put them in a json file, but for some reason i am only getting the last link (website and class see in the code). Any ideas, why is it not working properly?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

headers = {
>     "Accept": "*/*",
>     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0Safari/537.36"
> }

number = 0

for page_number in range(1, 2):
    url = f"https://www.sothebysrealty.com/eng/associates/int/{page_number}-pg"
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    src = req.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
    name_link = soup.find_all("a", class_="Entities-card__cta btn u-text-uppercase u-color-sir-blue palm--hide")

    all_links_dict = {}
    for item in name_link:
        value_links = ("https://www.sothebysrealty.com" + item.get("href"))

    all_links_dict[number + 1] = value_links

    with open("all_links_dict.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
    json.dump(all_links_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things I notice here.

Firstly, your page numbers `range(1,2)`. In python the stop is not included in the range so the for loop will only run once with a page number of 1.

Secondly, your `all_links_dict = {}` line is resetting the dictionary to an empty dict each time.

Lastly, you are opening the file each iteration of the loop in `'w'` mode and then json dumping which will overwrite any previous contents.

I would advise to adjust your range, move the dictionary initialisation out of the for loop and dump the dictionary to your file once at the end outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `all_links_dict[number + 1] = value_links` is not in your `for item in name_link` loop. Hence you only add to the dict once.

You must also increment number in the loop.

```py
for item in name_link:
    value_links = ("https://www.sothebysrealty.com" + item.get("href"))
    all_links_dict[number] = value_links
    number += 1
```

Comment: If I may add a comment for @Alberi , using a dict whose keys are actually indexes seems useless: simply use a list in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

---

> ```py
>     all_links_dict = {}
>     for item in name_link:
>         value_links = ("https://www.sothebysrealty.com" + item.get("href"))
>     all_links_dict[number + 1] = value_links
> ```

You're not updating `number` at any point, so only a value keyed to `1` gets saved every loop. Either use some derivation of `page_number` updates itself in each iteration, or add a line to increment `number` and bring it inside the inner loop.

```py
    all_links_dict = {}
    for item in name_link:
        value_links = ("https://www.sothebysrealty.com" + item.get("href"))
        number += 1
        all_links_dict[number] = value_links
```

---

> ```py
>     with open("all_links_dict.json", "w", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
>         json.dump(all_links_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
> ```

You should use `mode="a"` instead of `"w"` to append instead of over-writing in each iteration. However, you should be aware that the file will not be valid json (ie, you can't decode it any more) after a second iteration. Might be better to have a list that you append to every time and then write the list to json after (or at the end of) the loop.

---

**There's also the fact that *`for page_number in range(1, 2):`* will only lead to one iteration (where `page_number` is 1), so even with all this, only one page's info will be saved unless the range is expanded to include more pages.**